# Analog vs. Analogy

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> Sequoia is a fantastic communicator with the ability to convey complex ideas through imaginative samples and analogs.

I say it should be "analogy" rather than analog.

## Wiktionary

- [analog](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/analog#Noun) n. 1. *something that bears an analogy to something else*
- [analogy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/analogy#Noun) n. *A relationship of resemblance or equivalence between two situations, people, or objects, especially when used as a basis for explanation or extrapolation.*

## Questions

1. Is "analog" acceptable here?
2. Is "analog" *preferable* here?

Comment: What definitions have you found in dictionaries for each?

Comment: This use of noun/adjective *analog[ue]* is more "technical" (esp in domains such as zoology, chemistry, etc.) so it may work better in OP's exact context. *Analogy* is a much more general (and also specialised *literary*) term.

Comment: What do you mean by "*imaginative samples*"? Perhaps, you mean *examples*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analogue is the source from which an analogy is derived. Analogy is the thing you communicate, while analogue is the subject you are communicating about.

Use 'analogy', or rather 'analogies' in the sentence you've provided.